# Upload/Download pdf file from Vue front-end to Spring Backend using Axios

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, vue.js, axios

Using spring-boot 2.0.4 in my back-end and vue 2.5.16 / axios 0.18.0 in my front-end, I'm looking to Upload PDF files to my back-end db and retrieve them from my front-end.

Initially I was inspired by this example for the spring part: https://grokonez.com/frontend/angular/angular-6/angular-6-client-upload-files-download-files-to-mysql-with-springboot-restapis

And this gist for the Axios part:
https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743

My code is as follows:

- Uploading file in Vue with axios (the this.file variable is correctly set to my file using an "input type="file" " form input, AxiosService() is simply used to set the correct baseUrl and include an Authorization header with a token):

  ```
  createRecord() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", this.file);
    AxiosService()
      .post("/commands/material/", formData, {
         headers: {
           "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
         }
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log("File uploaded");
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  ```
- The spring part handling the upload looks as follow. In my Entity, the content field is defined as a byte[] annotated with @Lob.

  ```
  @BasePathAwareController
  @RequestMapping("/commands/material")
  public class MaterialCommandHandler {
      @Autowired
      MaterialRepository MaterialRepository;

      @RequestMapping(method=POST, path = "/")
      public ResponseEntity create(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
          MaterialEntity material = new MaterialEntity();
          material.setName(file.getOriginalFilename());
          material.setMimetype(file.getContentType());

          try {
              material.setContent(file.getBytes());
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          try {
              MaterialRepository.save(material);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              if (e instanceof DataIntegrityViolationException) {
                  throw new InvalidCommandException("Data is invalid for creation.");
              }
              throw(e);
          }
          return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(material.getId());
  }
  ```

With this code, The entry is correctly created in the DB, the content field in mysql is of type longblob.

- The method defined to return the content of the file:

  ```
  @RequestMapping(method = GET, path = "/download/{fileId}")
  public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFile(@PathVariable Long fileId) {
      Optional<MaterialEntity> fileOptional = materialRepository.findById(fileId);

      if(fileOptional.isPresent()){
          FrancaisMaterialEntity file = fileOptional.get();
          HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
          headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachement; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
          return ResponseEntity.ok()
              .headers(headers)
              .body(file.getContent());
      }
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
  }
  ```
- Finally the GET method sent from the front-end using axios:

  ```
  downloadFile() {
      AxiosService()
        .get(`/commands/material/download/${this.material.id}`, {
          responseType: "blob",
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
          const link = document.createElement("a");
          link.href = url;
          link.setAttribute("download", "CalculRanking.pdf");
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
          link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.errorMessage = error.response.data.message;
        });
    }
  ```

When trying to download the file, the pop-up in the navigator appears correctly, but unfortunately the .pdf file downloaded seems to be broken as Chrome states : "Error Failed to load PDF document" and I can't open it in Preview neither.

I'm thinking the problems comes from a wrong content interpretation at some point during the process. I did a lot of researches but none of the solution I tried made it work (Some of the things I tried: Adding the "Accept" header with value "application/pdf" and Setting "responseType: arrayBuffer" in the get request) so I decided to ask this question here. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you use postman or any rest client, you can download your pdf file by calling your rest /download/{fileId}

Comment: When I call the URL with postman, I receive a 200 Ok response with the Content-Disposition header correctly set to "attachement; filename="xxx.pdf"" and a body containing the binary content of my file (a long string of characters). But the file doesn't get downloaded.

Comment: I have a same error. Can you share your solution? @G.Serneels

Answer (score 1):

Could you change your method `getFile` by:

```
@GetMapping("/download/{fileId}")
@CrossOrigin
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getFile(@PathVariable(required = true, value = "fileId") Long fileId,
        HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

    Optional<MaterialEntity> fileOptional = materialRepository.findById(fileId);
    if (ensemblesRegles.isPresent()) {
        String fileName = "example.xlsx";
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        File file = new File(fileName); //the fileUtils is org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, fileOptional.get()); // Hope that your get return a byte[] array 
        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                // Content-Disposition
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + file.getName())
                // Content-Type
                .contentType(mediaType)
                // Contet-Length
                .contentLength(file.length()) //
                .body(resource);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, after applying these modifications, I'm now facing a "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation" Exception in my back-end. (I set an Accept:application/pdf header in my request but still have the same result)

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you take a look at [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).  This is designed to do exactly what you are trying to do and associated one, or more, content object's with Spring Data Entities.

To add this to your existing Spring Boot project you would do the following:-

> pom.xml

```
   <!-- Java API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-jpa-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.0</version>
   </dependency>

   <!-- REST API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

> MaterialEntity.java

```
@Entity
public class MaterialEntity {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private long id;

   ...other existing fields...

   @ContentId
   private String contentId;

   @ContentLength
   private long contentLength = 0L;

   @MimeType
   private String mimeType = "text/plain";

   ...
}
```

> MaterialEntityContentStore.java

```
@StoreRestResource(path="materialEntityContents")
public interface MaterialEntityContentStore extends ContentStore<MaterialEntity, String> {
}
```

This is all you need to do to get REST Endpoints that will allow you to store and retrieve content associated with each MaterialEntity.  How this actually works is very much like Spring Data.  When your application starts Spring Content will see the `spring-content-jpa-boot-starter` dependencies and know that you want to store content in your database.  It will then create a schema in the DB to do so and also inject a JPA implementation of the `MaterialEntityContentStore` interface.  It will also see the `spring-content-rest-boot-starter` and will inject REST endpoints that talk to the content store interface.  Meaning you dont have to do any of this yourself.

So, for example:

`curl -X POST /materialEntityContents/{materialEntityId} -F "file=@/path/to/image.jpg"`

will store the image in the database and associate it with the material entity whose id is `materialEntityId`.

`curl /materialEntityContents/{materialEntity}`

will fetch it again and so on...supports full CRUD and video streaming too actually.

Specificially, there is a (non-SpringBoot) MySQL example [here](https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content-examples/blob/master/spring-eg-content-jpa/src/test/java/examples/MysqlTest.java).

You could also decide to store the contents elsewhere like on the filesystem, or in S3 by swapping the `spring-content-jpa-boot-starter` dependency for the appropriate Spring Content Storage module.  Examples for every type of storage are [here](https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content-examples).

Front-end wise there aren't any vuejs examples unfortunately but we do have a angularjs 1.x example [here](https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content-gettingstarted/blob/master/spring-content-rest/complete/src/main/resources/static/index.html).  This may help with the front-end as they are similar technologies (in my limited experience with both!).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will take a look at Spring Content.